# Copy ranges in a table of rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel-2013

=copy_function name("cell ranges","cell ranges","cell ranges",workbook name_anddestinationcelladdress)

Hello i am new to programming i want a function to be like this =copy_function name("cell ranges",workbook name_andcelladdress) which will copy cells as mentioned to the desired workbook and opens the workbook with the copied values.

The cell ranges will also be like this suppose i have table from (a1:j15) then i want only  ("a1:a4","c1:e4") as observed the B column is not required to be copied to the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a sub rather than a function because you want to do more than just return a simple value.  Here is a very simple sub that you can adapt to your needs:

```
Sub CopyBlock(Sourze As String, Deztination As String)
    Dim FinalDestination As Workbook
    ary1 = Split(Sourze, "|")
    ary2 = Split(Deztination, "|")
    Set FinalDestination = Workbooks.Open(ary2(0))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ary1(0)).Range(ary1(1)).Copy FinalDestination.Sheets(ary2(1)).Range(ary2(2))
    FinalDestination.Save
    FinalDestination.Close
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
    Call CopyBlock("Sheet1|A1:B9", "C:\TestFolder\ABC.xls|NewName|C10")
End Sub
```

As you can see from examining the test sub **MAIN**, **CopyBlock** has two input parameters:

1. the sheet name of the source sheet | the address of the source range
2. the filespec of the destination file | the sheetname of the destination sheet | the upper left corner of the destination range.